# Netty doesn't complain if port is already used

Tags: java, netty

Following problem:
I expect an exception if a port is already used.

So I tried to start my server twice in a thread

```
    public void start() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup();
            EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup();

            ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
            serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(final SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new Decoder(Server.this));
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new Encoder(Server.this));
                        }
                    });

            serverBootstrap.bind(port).channel().closeFuture().syncUninterruptibly();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

But got no exception. I also tried to add an channel handler and catch a exception there, no luck :/

Surrounding the line with bind(port) to catch an exception has also no effect. But I noticed when I added a ChannelListener to the ChannelFuture, that one of the started instances never reached that point.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Only saw you call `serverBootstrap.bind(port).channel().closeFuture().syncUninterruptibly();` once in the code above. Could you provide complete code of how you start the server twice?

Comment: start(); start(); I put everything into void start()

Comment: You only called start once in the last line, did not see the other one.

Comment: No no. The start in the last line is referred to the thread. That has nothing to do with my public void start. I called my own void start() twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After binding you are directly taking the channel from the future, but it probably hasn’t finished at that point.
Try to wait for your bind to complete with `bind(port).sync()`.

See for reference https://www.baeldung.com/netty#6-server-bootstrap and https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html